# HashMap with List as a value in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am learning TypeScript and am trying to create a collection similar to the following in Java

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

I am unable to find any examples . Is it possible to do this in Typescript? Is there something similar to this?

Comment: You can use a `Map<string, string[]>` but I'd say it's better just to use a plain `{[k: string]: string[]}` aka `Record<string, string[]>` object unless you have some specific need for [the `Map` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)'s interface.  Your code example is really small, though; I could say `const hashMap = new Map<string, string[]>();`  or `const hashMap: Record<string, string[]> = {}` but I don't know if it helps with your use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashMap` contains only unique keys. So you can use simple object and assign array to key:

```js
let hash = {};
hash["bobtail"] = [];
hash["bobtail"].push({ age: 7, name: "miffy" });
console.log(hash)
```

Or try to use `Record<Keys, Type>`. [As docs says:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt)

> Constructs an object type whose property keys are Keys and whose
> property values are Type. This utility can be used to map the
> properties of a type to another type.

```
interface CatInfo {
  age: number;
  name: string;
}
 
type CatBreed = "bobtail" | "birman" | "maine";
 
const cats: Record<CatBreed, CatInfo[]> = {
  bobtail: [{ age: 7, name: "miffy" }],
  birman: [{ age: 8, name: "moorzik" }],
  maine: [{ age: 17, name: "mordred" }],
};
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the way to add an item to `Record<Keys, Type>`:

```
cats["bobtail"].push({ age: 11, name: "miffy" });
```

This is the way to get items from `Record<Keys, Type>`:

```
const bobtails: CatInfo[] = cats["bobtail"];
```

Comment: thanks! I want to add a key and the values will be a list.

Comment: @Mary please, see my updated answer

Comment: thank you! I was just reading about Record and it looks like it would work. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Mary I am glad that it helped to you!:)

Comment: I am trying to extend this example. What is the correct way to get a value from the Record? What is the correct way to add a value to a Record?

Comment: @Mary sorry for the late reply. I've updated my answer. Could you see, please, my updated reply?

Comment: I declared the variable as so: let acctRecord: Record<string, string[]>={}. However, when I push an  array I get "Argument of tye string[] is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'"  Is the declaration incorrect?

Comment: @StepUp- thanks for the help. I decided to use the hash as i am able to assign a array as a value, for the record, I am unable to do so